# Best way to load in a video and to grab images using c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, ffmpeg, directshow

I am looking for a fast way to load in a video file and to create images from them at certain intervals ( every second, every minute, every hour, etc.).

I tried using DirectShow, but it just ran too slow for me to start the video file and move to a certain location to get data and to save it out to an image. Even if I disabled the reference clock. Tried OpenCV, but it has trouble opening the AVI file unless I know the exact codec information. So if I know a way to get the codec information out from OpenCV I may give it another shot. I tried to use FFMPEG, but I don't have as much control over it as well as I would wish.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. This is being developed on a Windows box since it has to be hosted on a Windows box.

Comment: What file format and what codec?  If it's WMV, you can use the Windows Media Format SDK.

Comment: The majority of the videos are in AVI using MPEG-4 format. Though we do have some FLV files.

Comment: An AVI is just a collection of bitmaps. You can screen cap and bitblt during playback or maybe find a library that can pull out frames for you.

Comment: OpenCV itself uses DirectShow or FFMPEG to read the video so it won't give you any speedup comparing to them.

Comment: @AJG85 - not entirely true. Traditionally AVIs are files with no compression (bmps).  But the file format is extensible to host video from streaming codecs. In Seb's case, he has AVI files of MPEG video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MPEG-4 format is not an intra-coded format, so you can't just jump to a random frame and decode it on its own, as most frames only encode the differences from one or more other frames. I suspect your decoding is slow because when you land on a frame for which several other dependent frames to be decoded first.

One way to improve performance would be to determine which frames are keyframes (or sometimes also called 'sync' points) and limit your decoding to those frames, since these can be decoded on their own.

I'm not very familiar with DirectShow capabilities, but I would expect it has some API to expose sync points.

Also, I should mention that the QuickTime SDK on Windows is possibly another good option that you have for decoding frames from movies. You should first test that your AVI movies are played correctly in the QuickTime Player. And the QT SDK does expose sync points, see the section [Finding Interesting Times](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/QuickTime/RM/MovieBasics/MTEditing/G-Chapter/7WorkingWithMediaSam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000908-WorkingWithMediaSamples-DontLinkElementID_40) in the QT SDK documentation.

Comment: How would I use this to get each specified frame needed? Like if I needed an image for each frame every second in or every 30 seconds in.

Comment: Well, that's tricky. You would need to locate the closest keyframe to your target frame. You may have to decide on how far away from the target you are willing to go, if the nearest keyframe is too far away you may have no choice other than decode the target frame at a higher cost.

Comment: I've played around with the QT SDK, but it's not getting the results that I would like. I am mostly trying to create a console application that runs in the background and the only examples I can find online have me create a windows application. Is there any way I can "fake" a render so that I can just process the  video?

Comment: Take a look at this example app: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/MovieGWorlds

Comment: Thank you for all your help. This seems to work fairly well to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg's libavformat might work for ya...